# Emacs : auto-fill-mode - how to change line ending characters?

Tags: python, emacs

```
a = "hello\  
world"
```

In python , the continuation of an expression in another line needs '\' at the end of the first line. 
Emacs : Python mode : auto-fill-mode : whenever an expression exceeds 50 characters , how to customise auto-fill-mode for this kind of behaviour that it puts '\' in the current line and then do its default behaviour(move the excess in the next line) ?

Comment: You'll probably be able to get better help in [emacs.se].

Comment: @Barmar : Thanks

Comment: Please do not post the same question to SO and to emacs.SE - choose one or the other. Please delete one of the posts. Thx.